# How can i synchronise two threads on Linux C?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi3

so I would like through this code synchronize two threads. Let me explain, by the way, I want thread1 to read a value from a sensor and write it to a file called "integers.dat". The thread2 will therefore have the task of sending the content previously written on "integers.dat" to gnuplot (as indicated in the code below). So I would like the thread execution sequencing to be as follows:
thread1 (write), thread2 (send), thread1 (write), thread2 (send), and so on.
I tried to do this with mutex, but it did not work. The execution of both threads is always random.

code : 
`

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <pigpio.h>
     #include<sys/types.h>
     #include<signal.h>
     #include<unistd.h>
     #include<pthread.h>
     #include<semaphore.h>

     #define TRIGGER 5
     #define ECHO  6
     void *thread1_process (void *arg);
     void *thread2_process( void *arg);

   double start, stop,  measure;
   int i, val, it=0;
   FILE *fptr;
   FILE *gnu ; 

   static pthread_mutex_t my_mutex11;
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pthread_t th1, th2;
  void *ret;
  fptr=fopen("integers.dat", "w");
  gnu = popen("gnuplot -persistent","w");



  pthread_mutex_init (&my_mutex11, NULL); 

  pthread_create(&th1, NULL, thread1_process, NULL);
  pthread_create (&th2, NULL, thread2_process, NULL);   

 (void)pthread_join (th1, &ret);
 (void)pthread_join (th2, &ret);    


   }
   void *thread1_process (void *arg)
  {




  for(int i=0; i<20; i++) 
  {

   pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex11);

  printf("thread1 %d \n", i);
  gpioInitialise();
  gpioSetMode(TRIGGER , PI_OUTPUT);  // trigger
  gpioSetMode(ECHO , PI_INPUT);
  gpioWrite(TRIGGER, 0);
  gpioSleep(PI_TIME_RELATIVE, 0, 1);
  gpioWrite(TRIGGER, 1);
  gpioSleep(PI_TIME_RELATIVE, 0, 10); // sleep for 0.00001 seconds
  gpioWrite(TRIGGER, 0);
  while (gpioRead(ECHO) == 0)
  start = time_time();
  while (gpioRead(ECHO) == 1)
  stop = time_time();
  stop=time_time();
  measure = (stop-start) *17100.50;
  it++;
  val=measure;
  fprintf(fptr, "%d %d\n", it, val);
  gpioTerminate();

  pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex11);

   }


  pthread_exit(0);
  }
 void *thread2_process( void *arg)
 {


   for(int j=0; j<20; j++) 
  {

  pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex11); 

  printf("thread2 %d \n", j);   
  fprintf(gnu, "%s \n","plot 'integers.dat' with linespoints lw 3");

   pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex11);

  }
   pthread_exit (0);
   }`
```

Results

```
[thread1 0 
 thread2 0 
 thread2 1 
 thread2 2 
 thread2 3 
 thread2 4 
 thread2 5 
 thread2 6 
 thread2 7 
 thread2 8 
 thread2 9 
 thread2 10 
 thread2 11 
 thread2 12 
 thread2 13 
 thread2 14 
 thread2 15 
 thread2 16 
 thread2 17 
 thread2 18 
 thread2 19 
 thread1 1 
 thread1 2 
 Warning: empty y range [108:108], adjusting to [106.92:109.08]
 libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
 thread1 3 
 thread1 4 
 thread1 5 
 thread1 6 
 thread1 7 
 thread1 8 
 thread1 9 
 thread1 10 
 thread1 11 
 thread1 12 
 thread1 13 
 thread1 14 
 thread1 15 
 thread1 16 
 thread1 17 
 thread1 18 
 thread1 19]
```

Comment: `The execution of both threads is always random.` - if you don't want that, don't run threads. The execution of both threads is not random, they run simultaneously. Together. At the same time. If you want to run one after another, you can synchronize them with mutexes.

Answer (score 3):

aside from the obvious "why use two threads if one is always waiting anyway?" what you need to do is use some kind of "state" variable with the mutex:

```
// start here
#define STATE_INITIAL 0
// go here when step 1 finishes
#define STATE_STEP1 1
// go here when step 2 finishes
#define STATE_STEP2 2
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
int cur_state;

void wait_my_turn(int desired_state) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    if (cur_state == desired_state) return;
    pthread_mutex_unload(&my_mutex);
}

void finish_turn() {
    ++cur_state;
    if (cur_state == 3) cur_state = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}

// in main, initialize mutex, lock it, and set cur_state to STATE_INITIAL
// until you are ready for threads to start.  Then you need to set it
// to STATE_STEP1 to allow that thread to begin.
// in your threads, begin with wait_my_turn(STATE_STEPn)
// and call finish_turn() when done
```

...not a great example, but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: This is not sufficient to ensure that both threads run in bounded time, but it's about half way to a nice solution based on condition variables.  It just needs all the condition variable handling.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah, I was just trying to give them enough of an example to get them headed in the right direction.  It is, by no means, complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your answers.
I just found the solution to synchronise the two thread. A p_thread option must be used, it's p_thred_cond. You can follow the tutorial on the link below : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1513891-la-programmation-systeme-en-c-sous-unix/1514567-les-threads
Regards.